# Enter user authentication details for a printer?

Tags: printing, authentication, cups

I have a printer which is configured using the correct drivers. However, the printer requires user authentication (i.e. a username and password) to print. Where are authentication details usually entered in Unix systems? No dialog pops up when I print a job.

The printer is Sharp MX-2610N. I downloaded the Linux Cups PPD driver from [the manufacturer's site](http://www.sharpusa.com/CustomerSupport/ProductDownloads.aspx?model=MX-2610N). I am on Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Comment: What's the printer model? What printing software are you using? On what distribution?

Comment: The printer is Sharp MX-2610N. I downloaded the Linux Cups PPD driver from [here](http://www.sharpusa.com/CustomerSupport/ProductDownloads.aspx?model=MX-2610N). I am not sure what printing software you are referring to, I imagine its CUPS? I am on Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu uses Cups (unless you went out of your way to install something else). Does the printer correctly show up in the list? How did you install it — what did you do with the PPD file you downloaded? Does anything appear in `/var/log/cups/error_log` when you try to print?

Comment: Yep, the printer came with an installer script, which I just ran. The drivers appear correctly in `/usr/share/cups/model/sharp`. When I use the Printing module in Ubuntu, type the network address of the printer, it is found, and the correct drivers are located automatically. When I print a job, the feedback is `data sent successfully`; the log files are empty. I believe the job being rejected by the printer because the data is not being sent with the username/password credentials, which I have no way to pass at the moment.

Comment: Do you have a problem using the printer?

Comment: "the printer requires user authentication" How do you know that? Isn't it possible that the problem has nothing to do with authentication? I often have problems with lost print jobs but I guess authentication was never the reason. If you are not sure about that you should change the title (and content) of your question.

Comment: @jesterII What do you see in `/var/log/cups/error_log` or `/var/log/cups/page_log` when you print? Please copy-paste the full log of a print session. There is always something in at least one of these files.

Comment: To follow up @Braiam, there is no problem using the printer from Windows (PCL6), where I can enter my authentication details in a dialog in Printing Preferences. @Gilles, both those files are really empty for some reason. I have tried updating the device URI to `lpd://username:password@domain` but this feature is little documented and not really helping.

Comment: The `username:password@domain` is what you should use when defining/modifying the printer. (Remember to use %-encoding of reserved characters in the URI.)